# I need help fixing a error, i have tried multiple different ways to fix it but i have no success

Tags: discord.js

Hello every one this is my first post on stack overflow so sorry for formatting. anyways I need help fixing a error that no-one is able to help me with (discord js error). the code for the file that is having issues is in this link https://srcb.in/1RxMMrVyun

Answer (score 0):

Try using this i think the problem is of the hidden text

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```